# How to compile .NET Core 2.1 API project to target .NET Framework 4.7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

As the title suggests, I need to modify the target of compiling a .NET Core 2.1 API project to make it run as .NET Framwork 4.7.

I tried with the mere editing of the .csprj file but not enough, I think the problem is related to the packages included in Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, but I can not figure out how to solve. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Just for the news I need to do this thing to be able to publish in Hosting Aruba that currently does not have .NET Core included in IIS (and I do not even install it ...).

Thanks in advance for every suggestion.

Riccardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you rightly mentioned, Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is not compatible with .NET Framework.

From the project file remove the reference to it and replace it with the compatible package:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks! just added some pakages and it work!
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` indeed does not support .NET Framework 4.7 - so you **cannot** trivially do this.

It *might* be that you can use some manual sub-set of the things that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` targets, and get it to work - but this will only help if you are just using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` as a meta-package, and don't need something out of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` itself. So: you could try dropping the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` dependency, see what fails, and try adding packages back in. The list of things that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` imports can be seen by expanding "Dependencies" on the [nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/)

But: it is entirely possible that it *just isn't possible*.

Comment: Sounds like user wants to target 4.7 not because of client code on full but that the host doesn't have core on IIS box.  How about a self contained build?

Comment: @klabranche feel free to suggest it!

Comment: Except I think Core Hosting Bundle for IIS is still required.....  Couldn't remember... why I was using it as a comment.... do you remember?

Comment: It's needed.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041154/net-core-hosting-bundle So my idea would not have worked. :-)